# Mavenでminifyしたファイルへのリンクを自動で書き換える方法はありますか？

Tags: maven

`maven`で`grunt-usemin`のような動きは出来るんでしょうか？
ご教授お願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Maven`から`Grunt`を使うという方法はどうでしょうか？
[allegro/grunt-maven-plugin](https://github.com/allegro/grunt-maven-plugin)を使うと`Maven`のビルド処理で`Grunt`のタスクを実行することができます。(現時点での最新バージョンは`1.5.0`)

```
<build>
  ...
  <plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
      <groupId>pl.allegro</groupId>
      <artifactId>grunt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.0</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>npm</goal>
            <goal>grunt</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

行いたいタスクを`Gruntfile.js`に記述して、実行することができるようになるそうです。

cf. [Using Grunt with Java and Maven to Automate JavaScript Tasks | Heroku Dev Center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-grunt-with-java-and-maven-to-automate-javascript-tasks)

別のアプローチなどもあるようです。 [Making Maven Grunt.](http://addyosmani.com/blog/making-maven-grunt/)